# Unable to run any Meteor app

Tags: meteor

Recently I have discovered the Meteor framework and wanted to run some examples on my machine. I've done the following steps:

1. `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`
2. `meteor create myapp`
3. `cd myapp`
4. `meteor`

And as a result I get:

```
[[[[[ ~/workspace/myapp ]]]]]     

=> Started proxy.                             

/home/marcin/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at readSessionData (/home/marcin/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/auth.js:136:15)
    at Object.exports.getSessionId (/home/marcin/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/auth.js:1029:32)
    at /home/marcin/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/stats.js:66:23
```

I tried to reinstall Meteor and `meteor reset` but it won't help. I removed the app and created a new one but the problem still occurs. I managed to run the examples finally using Vagrant, but this is only some workaround and not a solution to the real problem. I have no idea why a fresh install of Meteor won't work on my machine. I am running 64bit Ubuntu 14.04. I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I don't know how this could have happened but can you try deleting the session file and see if it helps? `rm ~/.meteorsession`

Comment: @imslavko It worked! I removed this file and now meteor starts smoothly. I didn't know about the session file and I've never seen that anybody had problem with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @imslavko said, the solution to this problem is to remove the meteor session file: `rm ~/.meteorsession`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but can you do an update from within the project directory?

```
meteor update
```

Answer (score 0):

try this command

$ meteor -p 3006 
open port her and go to localhost:meteor -p 3006

Comment: You should add a description of why this resolves the OP's question.